# Stdev as expected distance from the mean

Tags: probability

Variance is defined as the expected square distance from the mean of a random variable: $Var\left( X\right) = E\left[{\left(X-E\left[X\right]\right)}^2\right]$. And $\sigma\left(X\right) = \sqrt{Var\left(X\right)}$.

But if $E\left(X\right)$ is the expected value of, say, the next random variable that you pick, then shouldn't the expected distance of the r.v. itself, $X$, from $E\left(X\right)$ be zero? And, as I understand, $E\left[X-E\left(X\right)\right]=0$.

So there seems to be a tension in the definition of variance/stdev as something like "expected distance from the mean", because variance and stdev are generally taken to be nonzero, whereas a different definition of expected distance from the mean equals zero.

To flesh this tension out, suppose that Player A and Player B are playing a game where Player B draws random variables from a $N\left(\mu,\sigma^2\right)$ distribution, for some fixed $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, and Player A has to wager on what the absolute distance from $\mu$ will be of $X$, the next r.v. to be picked. If Player A is close in their guess, they win money; if they are far off, B wins money. Suppose Player A is choosing between three different strategies for playing the game:

1. Always wager that the distance will be $0$
2. Always wager that it will be $\sigma^2$
3. Always wager that it will be $\sigma$

Under which strategy would Player A make the most money?

Comment: First you have to consider whether your *distance* can be negative or not. Second, remember that standard deviation is the square root of the variance, i.e. the square root of the expected square of the distance from the mean, which is not the expected distance from the mean.  Third, remember that the expected value is the *mean* not the *mode* (most likely) of a distribution; they are the same for a normal distribution, not not for all distribution

Comment: "shouldn't the expected distance of the r.v. itself, X, from E(X) be zero?" No; $E(X-EX)$ is zero because you're averaging positive and negative "distances", but $E(|X-EX|)$ is generally not zero.